# Augment a database query with data from a service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a query from models in my database, and some further optional information that comes from an external service, that will filter my existing query.  My current plan of attack is to use a temporary table from data that is returned by the service.  Is this type of thing advisable?  There aren't many places in the application where raw SQL is used, and I'd like to hear other's thoughts on this sort of thing.

I have a Job model that has many Assets and Parts.

My current query returns me a collection of all Jobs, and Assets and Parts.
The service I'm hitting returns an array of similar Parts to a specific part passed into the service.  The service returns a list of Part ids to filter on.

`rails 4.2`

Comment: That's a hard question to answer without some specific information. Can you provide an example? What fields are in your model, what information comes from the outside service, what do you need to query?

Comment: @moveson Sure, I'll try to add some pseudocode to get a better idea, but the gist should be the same regardless

Comment: Hi. I think this is going to fall into "overly broad / primarily opinion based" unless you can give us some code to work with, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to use raw SQL. You should be able to do something like this:

```
part_numbers = [123, 456, 789] # Part numbers returned by the outside service

similar_parts = Part.where(part_number: part_numbers)
```